# Как на языке PHP в DomPDF убрать отступ у текста и изображения внутри ячейки таблицы?

Tags: php, html, pdf, отступы, dompdf

Из PHP внизу PDF документа при его генерации из HTML создаётся разметка таблицы с двумя ячейками равной ширины, в которых находится текстовый прочерк(то есть _____), в левой ячейке рядом с ним может стоять изображение с подписью и(или)печатью. В результате добавления изображения прочерки подписей в ячейках находятся на разной высоте, что требуется устранить. Почитал что для того чтобы убрать отступ в html требуется присвоить img style display: block. В html это действительно решает проблему, при этом при генерации PDF документа в документе отступ остаётся. Пробовал и другие варианты предлагаемые для HTML - проблема отступа решается в html а в PDF остаётся. Как в DomPDF внутри ячейки таблицы убрать отступ который появляется у текста при размещении рядом с ним изображения.

В виде кода это выглядит примерно так:

```
<tr><td valign="bottom" height="150">___Подпись_продавца__<img src="...">__</td><td valign="bottom" height="150">___Подпись_покупателя_______</td></tr>
```

Атрибуты valign и height использую для того чтобы не зависимо от того будет ли при генерации PDF использоваться подстановка печати и подписи - прочерки под подпись находились бы в документе на той же высоте, в том числе для того чтобы если будет выбрано отсутствие вставки изображений подписи и печати после печати документа легко можно было бы установить реальные подпись и печать без наложения их на текст документа.